# Will ready set of SelectionKey be cleared after use in java NIO?

Tags: nio

In Java NIO, we usually use `SelectionKey.readyOps()` in order to get the ready-operations set. A subsequent accept/read/write IO operation will be performed correspondingly. Will this ready set be cleared automatically by JDK? Otherwise, an improper operation flag may be set next time we get the same `SelectionKey` by calling `Selector.selectedKeys()`.

Answer (score 1):

The `readyOps` are cleared and set by the `Selector`. You don't have to do anything with them yourself: indeed you can't, as there is no API.

Comment: How to? It seems there is not method provided to clear it.

Comment: Iterator.remove() only removes a reference to the SelectionKey instance from the selected Set. It doesn't change anything in the instance.